# How to identify the Azure Active Directory Joined device over https connection without login

Tags: azure, web-applications, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I have an web application made in .net core 2.2. My goal is to expose the web application to a list of hosts that is only Azure AD joined without any UI login.
I got few PC that were hybrid joined in the starting of the project, so I could use System.Net.Dns to find the Hostnames and whitelisting those hosts. It works fine.
I got problem right now that the new PCs that are only AAD joined and our Domain Controller will not return host names.
My question is how can I get hostnames of those AAD joined PCs?               I need to use those names in my application, because it tells the location of the PCs.
Is there any API in Azure can return device information for a certain tenant by giving an IP adresse?

Answer (score 0):

The hostname of the device is saved as the NAME attribute on the device object. However, Azure AD will not save the IP address information when you join a machine to Azure AD.

So, I do not think if your application only has the IP address that the device, then you will not be able to query the device from Azure AD to get the hostname.

Comment: It is an web application, there is no login. If MSAL.js support to get deviceID from Azure, so I can use deamon project to get the device name from our tetant